# Change fa icon from css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, icons

Here I have a fa icon inside  an arrow, I wanna change it for fa fa-plus-square, but no touching html, instead make it from css. How to achieve it?

```
<div class="footer-text">
   <h4 itemprop="name">LOREM IPSUM</h4>
   <p class="text" itemprop="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa...</p>
   <span class="arrow"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Youll have to use javascript or jquery to change it if doing in html is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

To override Fontawesome icon, the character code of `fa-plus-square` is required.

[Ref: plus-square](https://fontawesome.com/icons/plus-square)

the character code of plus-square is `f0fe`. you just need to override `fa-chevron-right:before` with it.

```css
span.arrow > i.fa.fa-chevron-right:before {
  content: "\f0fe";
}
```

**Complete Snippet:**

```css
span.arrow > i.fa.fa-chevron-right:before {
  content: "\f0fe";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="footer-text">
  <h4 itemprop="name">LOREM IPSUM</h4>
  <p class="text" itemprop="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa...</p>
  <span class="arrow"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Any idea why it wouldn't work? I added the new fa char code to the `::before` element, I can see it in the dev inspector when reloading the page, not crossed out, but the original fa icon is still the one showing: https://jsfiddle.net/STaRDoGG/aLjeu501/7/

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the font-awesome.css and change the code inside the `fa-chevron-right` class to be a different icon, or just in a different css file add the `fa-chevron-right` class and add the necsary code to display the icon you want but you have to be sure that the new css file is declared after the font awesome file.